# (PHP) Spreading array contents equally across a fixed number of columns

Tags: php, arrays

I am going nuts here - hope you can help me figure this out! What is supposed to be very simple math is utterly confusing me.

```
$columns = 3;
$items = range(1,20);
$total = count($items);

$col1 = ???; $col2 = ???; $col3 = ???;

// $col1 must be an array of (1,2,3,4...)
// $col2 must be an array of (8,9,10,11...)
// $col3 must be an array of (15,16,17,18...)

COL1       COL2        COL3
1          8           15
2          9           16
3          10          17
4          11          18
5          12          19
6          13          20
7          14
```

The above is a visual example of what I am trying to achieve. Basically, for any given number of items in an array and for any given number of columns, how do I produce n number of arrays (equalling number of columns) that are as equal length as possible. If equal length is not possible (as in the example above), they must be spread out as evenly as possible and the last array must be the shortest.

Any guidance on how I construct $col1/2/3 in the example above would be much appreciated!

Please ignore the fact that I used range and integers to generate the array - this is just to simplify the example. Assume the array will contain strings.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any reason why you're not just sorting the array, creating a for loop and populating the cols that way?

Comment: That would be fine, but I'm stuck at the calculation to determine how many items to populate before moving on to the next column. That is basically the problem I am stuck at with the example above. I just used arrays to simplify the presentation.

Comment: $total / $column? I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you mean I suppose? Either that or you're missing the obvious ..

Comment: Yes, that would be fine, but only when it is a clean division. When it is not, you potentianlly end up with a situation where the last column has far fewer items than the other columns, when they could be spread out better.

Comment: Found the solution: http://bran.name/dump/split-array-into-equal-sized-chunks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want to use `array_chunk`, but you need to calculate the chunk size yourself:

```
list($col1, $col2, $col3) = array_chunk($items, ceil($total / $columns));
```

Comment: Beautiful and succint. Thanks. `ceil` was what I was missing. :)

Comment: For 19 this will return 7, 7, 5.

Comment: Yes, when ideally, we want 7, 6, 6. Ho hum. Not a dealbreaker though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
list($col1,$col2,$col3)=array_chunk($arrofstrings,$colcount);
```

Comment: I thought array_chunk will divide the array into sub-arrays that have $colcount items in each? If this is the case, that is not what I want. I tried array_chunk in my example above and it gave me 7 sub arrays with three items each, except for the last, which had two items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemsInColumn = ceil($total / $columns);
```

Comment: @moteutsch This will result in 7. Which can be used in a loop that will give 7, 7, 6. Or you're aware of a method that allows you divide 20 by 3 and have the same number of items in each column?

Comment: Excuse me, I miss-typed. I meant to say that for 19 it will return 7, 7, 5.

Comment: @moteutsch Got it, you're right. The "7, 6, 6" would be better in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = 3;
$items = range(1, 20);

$rows = array_chunk($items, $columns);

$columns = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
        $columns[$i][] = $row[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this return 7,6,6 in the case of 19?

Comment: Hmm I get a weird memory error when trying this function. I am trying to run this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2tpL/) - unfortunately, am not smart ernough to debug. Help please? :)

Comment: Error is this: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes). Anything to do with your code or is it my system?